# How do you put armor on a Horse in Minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to left-click to put armor on a horse, but couldn't put it on.

Answer (score 3):

Get onto a tamed horse, open your inventory, and put the horse armor in the slot.
[image]

Comment: You can also shift-right-click to put on horse armor on PC.

Comment: Of course the horse needs to be tamed.